# How to select an element if its Xpath is changing?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I wrote a piece of code to select an element of the page (there are some description of a product):

```html
 <h2 class="box-header dgrey mt30">
            Amplasare        </h2>
        <ul class="itemtable box-columns">
            
    <li>
     <div class="fields">Strada</div>
     <div class="values">бульвар Куза-Водэ </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div class="fields">Numărul casei</div>
     <div class="values">20/1 </div>
    </li>
                <ul class="itemtable">
                 <li>
                  <div class="fields">Sectorul</div>
                  <div class="values">Botanica</div>
                 </li>
                </ul>        </ul>
```

```
try:
    adresa = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="anItemData"]/ul[4]')))
    adresa = adresa.text
    adresa = adresa.split('\n')
    adresa = {k:v for k, v in zip(adresa[0::2],adresa[1::2])}
except TimeoutException:
    adresa = 1
```

If it finds the content in the row  **'Amplasare'**  it does the task right.
[image]
giving the result:

```
adresa = {'Sectorul': 'Botanica', 'Strada': 'бульвар Куза Водэ`, 'Numarul casei':'20/1'}
```

But sometimes the users do not complete all the fields and the content is lacking:
[image]

In that case it selects other content on the page giving:
`adresa = ['079 104 207']`
Why is that haping and how to set it to return a dict with `NaN` values as keys in the case the contents are not displayed on the page?

Comment: If you need to find "Amplasare" then why are you not starting there?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I need that the parser collect the values for `Strada`, `Sectorul` and `Numarul casei` but when this section on the web page is not filled by the user, instead of getting as the answer a empty dict it gives me the  phone number or the information that is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to avoid using indexes in `XPath`, but bound to element with exact text:

```
try:
    adresa = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[normalize-space(text())="Amplasare"]/following-sibling::ul')))
    adresa = adresa.text
    adresa = adresa.split('\n')
    adresa = {k:v for k, v in zip(adresa[0::2],adresa[1::2])}
except TimeoutException:
    adresa = 1
```

This should allow to scrape values only if block with header `"Amplasare"` is found on page